# switch (true) + case по array[key]

Tags: php

Подскажите, почему срабатывает только первый case, а второй нет?

PHP-код:

```
$i = array('a1' => 'Hello', 'a2' => ' World!');
    switch (true) {
        case isset($i['a1']):
            $p .= $i['a1'];
            break;

        case isset($i['a2']):
        $p .= $i['a2'];
        break;
    }        
    echo $p;
```

Результат: Hello

Comment: Потому что первый case - true?

Comment: но и второй тоже true

Comment: Значит пора открыть мануал и почитать про `switch`.

Comment: В мануале написано, что switch сравнивает переменную со множеством значений, т.е. true со всеми case.

Comment: Прочитайте до конца, пожалуйста. Особенно обратите внимание на предложение  __PHP продолжает исполнять операторы до конца блока `switch` либо до тех пор, пока не встретит оператор `break`.__

Comment: Потому-что у вас после сравнения срабатывает выход из функции break; и дальше не идёт сравнение

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно нужно тщательно читать мануал!